# "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext' available" while testing a controller

Tags: spring-boot-test

I'm testing my first RestController with Spring Boot. Following many examples found on the Internet, I've set the test as follows, but Spring isn't able to autowire the WebApplicationContext:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CollectionController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = DefaultTestConfiguration.class)
public class CollectionControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void postTest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(post("/collection/")
                  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                  .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The same happens with MockMvc if I try to autowire it instead of setting it explicitly in the @Before method.

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ICollectionService collectionService() {
        return new MockCollectionService();
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/collection")
public class CollectionController {

    private ICollectionService collectionService;

    @Autowired
    public CollectionController(ICollectionService collectionService) {
        super();
        this.collectionService = collectionService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public CreateCollectionDTO createCollection(@RequestParam String collectionId) {
        return new CreateCollectionDTO(collectionService.createCollection(collectionId));
    }
}
```

and my spring dependencies in pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you'll provide.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I find it myself.
The issue was with the @ContextConfiguration statement, more precisely: the value AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class for the loader parameter was preventing the WebApplicationContext to be instantiated.

After removing the "loader" parameter, everything went fine: the @Bean methods of my configuration class where properly executed and the MockMvc was created by simply Autowiring it (no @Before method needed).